# iPhone - Network code inside model classes - Code Design Issue

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 Model classes, *`User`* and *`Place`*.

I need to get the user's nearby places, data which I get from my server.
User has a property of currentLocation.

Since the Place class feels more appropriate to have a method like `getNearByPlacesForLocation` I thought of having it as a static method inside my Place class.

I'm wondering about 2 things:

1. Does this sound like the right architecture ?
2. Does putting a network code inside my model (in this example, inside `getNearByPlacesForLocation`) is the right way to go ? or perhaps I should Use some singelton like 'NetworkManager' ? but again in that case my model wouldn't be reusable since it depends on this 'NetworkManager' class.
   How would you solve it ?

After some thinking I got to this design :
    **User.m**

```
@implementation User

@synthesize currentLocation;

- (NSArray*) getNearbyPlaceForCurrentLocation
{
    [Place getNearByPlacesForLocation:currentLocation];
}

@end
```

**Place.m**

```
#import "Place.h"
#import "NetworkServicesDataSource.h"

@implementation Place

static id<NetworkServicesDataSource> _networkDataSource;

+(void) setNetworkManager:(id<NetworkServicesDataSource>)networkDataSource
{
    _networkDataSource = networkDataSource;
}

+(NSArray*) getNearByPlacesForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) loc
{
    return [_networkDataSource getNearByPlacesForLocation:loc];
}

@end
```

**NetworkServicesDataSource.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol NetworkServicesDataSource <NSObject>

-(NSArray*) getNearByPlacesForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) loc;

@end
```

That way I can do some sort of dependency injection and don't rely on any specific networking implementation inside my Place class.

I'm still curious though if having those methods inside each of the model classes is better than having a '`NetworkManager`' singelton who's single responsibility is to get me the data I request from the server, where I can reference this '`NetworkManager`' inside my `UIViewControllers`.
I feel like interacting with model objects and asking data from them inside my `UIViewController` is more clean and structured, but I'd be happy to hear other peoples' opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are saying perfect. Your UI Code and controller code should be separate, this is cz your same code will be resued if you want to put it in some other application, or if you want to make another iPad/iphone version of your app. you just need to change the UI settings, and if you develop a network manager class, you may place it easily to any other app, more over your code becomes independent and very easy to maintain.